# Are students who pay tuition through scholarship eligible for deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes

If the University is paying my tuition and part of my fees, can I still claim the `Tuition and Fees` deduction on my 1040?

More specifically, can I claim one or the other or both?

I looked at [Form 8917](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8917.pdf), but the instructions did not say anything about my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the university pays your fees directly, you can't claim the deduction, but on the plus side it means that money is not taxable income for you.  If they pay *you* money (in the form of a stipend, etc.) and you use that to pay your fees yourself, then it is taxable income for you, but you can deduct your tuition expenses.

What you can't do is double-dip and try to get both.  If they pay your tuition, *they* paid it, so you can't deduct it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. You cannot claim something you didn't pay.